# Updating my database with the changed elements in a table

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, html-table

I'm making an address book of a company's tech support contacts and the admin gets access to all addresses in a form of a table. In this table, he can add, delete and make changes to data in the same page.

I have set up the `add` and `delete` functions successfully, but I struggle a lot with the `edit`. I'm using node, express, mongodb and vanilla javascript.

I'm still a newbie in web developement and there is are words I may use wrong, so sorry in advance!

*(Excuse my french, but most of the words mean the same in english.)*

**My HTML**

```html
<div>
  <input id="edit" type="button" value="Editer" onclick="return edit()">
  <input id="valider" type="hidden" value="Valider" onclick="return valider()">
</div>

<table id='myTable'>
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th>Nom de l'entreprise</th>
      <th>Téléphone 1</th>
      <th>Téléphone 2</th>
      <th>Mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% companies.forEach(function(company){ %>  //I loop through my db
    <tr class="compName">
      <td hidden id='_id' > <%= company._id %> </td>
      <td> <input id="name" class="readonly" type="text" value=" <%= company.name %>"     readonly style="border: none" onblur="change(this)">    </td>
      <td> <input id="phone" class="readonly" type="text" value=" <%= company.phone %>"   readonly style="border: none" onblur="change(this)">    </td>
      <td> <input id="phone2" class="readonly" type="text" value=" <%= company.phone2 %>" readonly style="border: none" onblur="change(this)">    </td>
      <td> <input id="mail" class="readonly" type="text" value=" <%= company.mail %>"     readonly style="border: none" onblur="change(this)">    </td>
    </tr>
  <% }) %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**My Script**

```
<script>

function edit() {
    var editComp = document.getElementsByClassName("readonly");
    var edit = document.getElementById('edit').type = 'hidden'; //get the edit button and hide it
    var valider = document.getElementById('valider').type = 'button'; //then unhide the validate button so I can use it

    for (var i = 0; i < editComp.length; i++) { //remove the readonly for each td so I can edit it
      editComp[i].removeAttribute('readonly');
      editComp[i].setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid red;");
    };
}

function valider() {
    var editComp = document.getElementsByClassName("readonly");
    var edit = document.getElementById('edit').type = 'button'; //unhide the edit button
    var valider = document.getElementById('valider').type = 'hidden' //hide my validate button

    for (var i = 0; i < editComp.length; i++) { //put back the readonly for each td so its uneditable
      editComp[i].setAttribute('readonly', true);
      editComp[i].setAttribute("style", "border: none;");
    };
}


function change(element) { //when the input gets unfocused, I assume that's because changes happened
    var setChanged = element.setAttribute("class", "readonly changed"); //I mark all changed element

    /*I want to udapte my database with the changed elements
      I was thing of getting the hidden company._id and the id of the changed element so I can update them specifically*/
}
</script>
```

So I was think of getting the col[0] of the changed row, which is the _id of my changed element, so I can target it for updating in my database, but I don't know how I should do it.

Thanks!